# Отображение нескольких приложений на одной странице, наследование шаблонов

Tags: python, django

Только начинаю разбираться в django. Застрял на этом моменте. Необходимо отображать разные блоки на странице, каждый блок - это, грубо говоря, отдельное приложение. Хотелось бы все-таки разделить их.
Но не получается реализовать это. Отображается только один блок.
Главный шаблон main.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
{% block block1 %}
{% endblock %}
{% block block2 %}
{% endblock %}
{% block block3 %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

В каждом приложении есть своя папка templates, в которой лежит шаблон c `{% extends 'main.html' %}`
По отдельности отображается, вместе нет. Я понимаю, что block не равно view, но как тогда организовать совместное отображение? И на чей urls.py тогда ссылаться?

Answer (score 1):

В каждом блоке где вам нужно импортировать другой шаблон делайте так -

app/template1.html

```
<div>Бла бла бла</div>
<div>{% include 'app/template2.html' %}</div> (здесь вы импортируете в div шаблон который нужно загрузить, так же если вы импортируете страницу с какими то параметрами их так же нужно передать: {% include 'app/templates2.html' with form=form %})
<div>Бла бла бла</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется, для этого дела вам отлично подойдут темплейттеги "template tags".

Вы создаёте необходимый темплейт тег для каждого приложения, вставляете их в нужное место, а они в свою очередь, подтягивают логику из необходимых приложений. Только увлекаться ими не стоит.

Также возможно вам подойдут вставки {% include "foo/bar.html" %}

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include